# How to use timing function for slowly speed up scaling function with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scale, skaction

I have a sprite that I'm trying to scale out. I'm using the scaleTo skaction to do this... I want it to slowly ease in. And this was my initial solution:

```
    let scal = SKAction.scale(by: 100, duration: 10)
    scal.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeIn
```

The problem is that as it scales out, since it is scaling out so much it appears to slow down. So I need to use the timeingFunction in order to write a custom easeIn for the action.

https://youtu.be/CE-B27gSXJI

In the video, you can see that it appears that it starts off fast and slows down. It only appears this way because I'm going a scale, and the bigger you go the slower it will appear...

Problem: I have no clue how to do this with the timing function, and I haven't been able to find a good source to use as a reference?

Any help would be appreciated and thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the Sprite Kit Utils from Ray Wenderlich for an example on how one can write an easing function: https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils Specifically, look at SKTTimingFunctions.swift and SKTEffects.swift.

There are some neat functions to give you better control of your easing. You might even want to use the easing functions that are defined there without changes, most of them work pretty well. For reference on how each easing function behaves, you can look at http://easings.net

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh wow! This is perfect and is surprisingly simple for the most part...

To be clear, this is how I would use such a function:

scal.timingFunction = SKTTimingFunctionQuarticEaseIn( 10)

I'm not at my computer to test this out, but how would I determine the CGFloat I pass into the function?

Thanks!

Comment: @Discoveringmypath Glad it helps! I wouldn't pass the CGFloat into the function, but just do let scaleEffect = SKTScaleEffect( /* all the input paramaters that are required */); let scaleEffect.timingFunction = SKTTimingFunctionQuarticEaseIn; node.runAction(SKAction.actionWithEffect(scaleEffect))

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now I'm confused on how this timing function works... Is there a way to use the timing functions alone without his helper class... I would prefer to understand how to use them and what is going on rather than just plug and play... I appreciate the help so far and I'm going to accept your answer. Can you explain how I could use the timing functions alone?

Comment: @Discoveringmypath As I understand, in the first update the node scale gets adjusted by x percent. With each update, the rate at which x grows increases. So in the 2nd update, the scale increases by x + x' percent. In the 3rd update, it's x + x'' + x''', etc. Sorry I can't give you more details, I'm not so knowledgeable on easing functions myself, that's why I use Ray's functions with a bit of tweaking :)

Comment: Thank you for the added understanding. I wish Apples documentation went into this a bit more. I also posted an answer to show how I ended up doing it...

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to mark the answer above correct but this ended up being my solution and I wanted to share as it is simple to implement.

I don't fully understand how this works but when you specify the function for the timingFunction you have to include **"t in"**. Then you can use this t to manipulate the timing of the animation.

So if you look at the links above, you can get the desired affect by using what is contained in the functions in Ray's SKTTimingFunctions.swift.

The below code shows how I used it; my timing function starts of slow and then slowly picks up speed... Again see the links above and you can get an idea.

```
let scal = SKAction.scale(by: 100, duration: 10)
scal.timingFunction = { t in
    return t*t*t*t*t
}
```